# Is there a way to write an UPDATE statement to fix multiple rows with bad data?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am trying to fix a data error in a SQL Server database.

There are values that are using the wrong partId from the wrong factory.

I can get a list of all the machines with wrong parts like this:

```
---machines using wrong parts from wrong factory 88 and 89:
SELECT ml.machineId, ml.machineName, mp.machineId, mp.partId, pc.officialIdentifierId 
FROM industry.machineParts mp
INNER JOIN partsCatalog pc ON mp.partId = pc.partId
INNER JOIN machineList ml ON mp.machineId = ml.machineId
WHERE pc.factoryId IN (88,89)
```

I have one ID that is common amoung them in the machineParts table and that is the `officialIdentifierId` ID.

But I am unsure of how to change all the rows in the machineParts table with partIds from factory 88 and 89 with the new factory 100 partIds.

The machineParts table looks like this:

```
machineId       partId
----------------------
7623741         123 
8927661         124
6471982         125
```

So if a machine has an old partId from factory 88 or 89, I need to replace it with the partId from factory 100.

The partsCatalog table has the factoryId value and looks like this:

```
partId  |   name        |   factoryId   |   officialIdentifierId
--------------------------------------------------------------
123           OilFil                88          A-00-900c     
124           O_Filter              89          A-00-900c
125           Oil Filter            100         A-00-900c
```

So the correct machineParts table should look like this after the fix:

```
machineId       partId
----------------------
7623741         125
8927661         125
6471982         125
```

I tried this update statement to fix all the bad rows:

```
UPDATE machineParts SET partID = (SELECT partID FROM  partsCatalog WHERE factoryId = 100)
WHERE partID IN(123, 124)
```

But I get this error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
> subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
> an expression. The statement has been terminated.

Is there a way to fix all the bad rows with one query?

Thanks!

Comment: The error is telling you the problem here, what about the error aren't you sure about?

Comment: SQL Server is expecting your subquery to result in a single value; when you run it on its own, how many rows do you get? It's more than 1.

Comment: @Larnu I looked up the error on the Microsoft site for SQL Server.  I think I understand why I am geting that error.  But I think I am lucky I got the error becuase I think if that query worked it would have ruined table data.

Comment: @Stu thanks I understand the error now, but I am lucky I got error.  Do you know of a way of fixing all the entries in my `machineParts` table that are using the wrong partId from old factories? I can fix each row by itself, but that would be over 5000 rows.

Comment: You need to build the query to select the correct value which you can then simply turn into an update statement, or possibly use in an updatable CTE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there only one part at factory 100 with an officialIdentifierId of A-00-900c?

If so,

```
UPDATE machineParts 
    SET partID = (SELECT partID 
                  FROM  partsCatalog 
                  WHERE factoryId = 100
                    AND officialIdentifierId = 'A-00-900c'
                 )
WHERE partID IN (123, 124)
```

Comment: Yes the `partsCatalog` contains the `officialIdentifierId` column.  So there would only be one row that has a factoryId of 100 and an officialIdentifierId of A-00-900c.

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell, does the given query do what you want?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you have multiple records with `factoryId = 100`. You can "fix" this with a TOP 1 as below, but you must be certain that the `partID` is the same on all records with the subquery's `factoryId`:

```
UPDATE machineParts SET partID = (SELECT TOP(1) partID FROM  partsCatalog WHERE factoryId = 100)
WHERE partID IN(123, 124);
```

This says "just give me the partID on the **first** record with factoryId 100". You can also tweak the subquery to give you the most recent one, assuming there's a `createdOn` field as an example:

```
UPDATE machineParts SET partID = (SELECT TOP(1) partID FROM  partsCatalog WHERE factoryId = 100 ORDER BY createdOn DESC)
WHERE partID IN(123, 124);
```

Comment: thank you, there are multiple records in my `partsCatalog` table with a `factoryId = 100`. But it's the column called `officialIdentifierId` that unifies the data. So even if `machineParts` table has wrong partIds.  I can look them up by using  `officialIdentifierId`, because that is the same for both the wrong factoryIds and the correct factoryId. But I am trying to find a single query to update them all at once.

Comment: Without an order criteria, top (1) doesn't get the *first* row, there is no such thing as a  *first* row, it could be different on the next execution.

Comment: That's right @Stu, it's the "first" one the engine comes across given whatever query plan it came up with this time.